# How do I perform an IF/ELSE statement using data from a database on wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get the below code to perform an `if/else` statement.
I am trying to say look in the database table `'re_terms'`  and `if` the `'term_id'  is '15'` display this code, otherwise display this code.

I realise what I have at the moment is saying `$product_id` is `15` so it always displays the first set of html.

I am performing this in wordpress.

```
<?php 
$product_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id 
                              FROM re_terms 
                              WHERE name = 'contract'");
echo $product_id;

if ($product_id == '15'): ?>
      <div class="grid__medium-4 grid__columns grid__columns_mobile text-c 
buttons">
        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/stockists"><span 
class="button_light">Find a stockist!!!!</span></a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/brochure"><span 
class="button_light">Request a brochure</span></a>
      </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="grid__medium-4 grid__columns grid__columns_mobile text-c 
buttons">
         <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/stockists"><span 
 class="button_light">Find a stockist</span></a>
         <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/brochure"><span 
 class="button_light">Request a brochure</span></a>
    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: do `var_dump($product_id);` instead of `echo $product_id;` and let us know what you got actually. Also change `$product_id == '15'` to `$product_id == 15`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have done as you said and got: string(2) "15"

Comment: then your code is working fine. so what's the problem here?

Comment: it is suggesting that they all have a term_id of 15

Comment: What do you mean _all have a term_id of 15_? Your SQL is always selecting same row - the one `WHERE name='contract'`. That's a row with `term_id=15`. Do you say you have many rows `WHERE name='contract'`?